# NHibernate session.Query<ISomeInterface>().Count returns wrong count

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

I faced the problem with getting correct count of objects by interface:

```
var count = session.Query<IDirty>().Count();
```

There are 2 classes that implement interface IDirty. Count returns the number of objects of one class, ignoring the second.

QueryOver just throws an exception that the item is not unique.

```
var count2 = session.QueryOver<IDirty>().RowCount();
```

Internally it uses SingleOrDefault method, what explains why it fails...

Getting the list of items is working correctly - list includes objects of both types:

```
var list= session.Query<IDirty>().ToList();
```

Is there any workaround to get correct count without enumerating all items?

Comment: in the QueryOver scenario, does it change something if you project on a single property (id?) and perform the count on that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
session.QueryOver<IDirty>().ToRowCountQuery().List<int>().Sum()
```

Comment: var count = session.QueryOver<IDirty>().ToRowCountQuery().List<int>().Sum(); worked!

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, this is a bug, although I can see why it would be non-trivial to fix it.

You can open an issue at https://nhibernate.jira.com. In the meantime, just use separate queries for each type implementing `IDirty.`